# Google Plus button fails to load. Uncaught gapi.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

Everytime I launch my page containing a google plus icon I see the following error:

```
Uncaught gapi.load: Pending callback https://ssl.gstatic.com/webclient/js/gc/23980661-3686120e/googleapis.client__plusone.js plusone.js:16
```

Any idea where this is coming from?  This is the [dating site](http://accentudate.com/my_score.php) I see the error on.

Comment: i can see the +1 button the on the link you provided..

Comment: The error shows up in the google chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes where you want the button to appear:

```
<g:plusone size='small' count='false' href='http://www.zxclasses.com'></g:plusone>
```

This goes just before your  tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Google says the script should appear after the final button, but some browsers error with something like NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED, if the code appears anywhere else than directly above

for IE7, i dont think so its working ...

Comment: wow...after clicking the plus one icon I now see this error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://accentudate.com/my_score.php from frame with URL

Comment: this message suggests that the problem is the communication between two pages coming from different servers, btw such messages appear even related to two pages coming from the same server:

Comment: My thinking is that it is enough that two pages coming from the same server. change their domain to something else (eg from www.google.com to google.com) and communicate for the message to be shown.

Comment: its harmless so dont bother about it.. making a cross domain request will force javascript to show this error, however all your code must do what its suppose to do.

Answer (score 2):

Did you duplicate the Javascript code part every time you have a +1 button (it's very likely that you have more than 1 +1 buttons on a single webpage)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
</script>
```

I had the same problem as yours, I removed the above Javascript where it is duplicated and only included it once with the `<head>` tag of my webpage.

The error stopped showing up after that :)

I checked out your dating site a few minutes ago, still saw the error so hope this helps :)

Comment: I do something like this `$(document).ready(function() { if ($("g\\:plusone").length == 0) return; /* google plus code here */ })` in a common script file.